# Why next.js next.config.js is redirection not working?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have defined my redirect in next.config.js files you can see here:

```
  module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/feedback',
        destination: '/contact-us',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/coins',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/all/views/all',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/tokens/views/all',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/coin/views/all',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/views/non-mineable',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/views/non-mineable/page/:slug',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/coin/views/non-mineable',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/coin/views/non-mineable/page/:slug',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/coin/views/non-mineable/page',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/coin/views/mineable',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/tokens/views/non-mineable/page/:slug',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/tokens/page',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/favourite-coins',
        destination: '/watchlist',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/favourite-coins/page',
        destination: '/watchlist',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/favourite-coins/page/:slug',
        destination: '/watchlist',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

But when i open url in production it gives this error:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `protocol` of 'undefined' or
> 'null'. at getLocationOrigin
> (/node_modules/next/dist/ne
> at parseRelativeUrl
> (/node_modules/next/dist/nex
> x x                                                xx my_app_name >
> at prepareDestination
> (/node_modules/next/dist/n
> x x                                                xx my_app_name >
> at Object.fn
> (/node_modules/next/dist/next-serve
> x x                                                xx my_app_name >
> at Router.execute
> (/node_modules/next/dist/next-
> x x                                                xx my_app_name >
> at Server.run
> (/node_modules/next/dist/next-serv
> x x                                                xx my_app_name >
> at Server.handleRequest
> (/node_modules/next/dist
> x x                                                xx my_app_name >
> at
> /node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:1:1824
> x x                                                xx my_app_name >
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)

Can anyone help?

Comment: What makes you think the issue is related to the `redirects` in `next.config.js`?

Comment: I don't know but what's this issue is about?